# Build error: COMReference .NET CORE 3.0: AxImp not found

Tags: .net-core, reference, com, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to compile a .NET CORE 3.0 application that has a COM reference. Unfortunately when trying to build that application that has the reference, I am getting a build error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): 
error MSB3091: 
Task failed because "AxImp.exe" was not found, or the correct Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. 
The task is looking for "AxImp.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the 
InstallationFolder value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86. 

You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  
1) Install the Microsoft Windows SDK.  
2) Install Visual Studio 2010.  
3) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.  
4) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.
```

[image: vs ide]

I understand that something is probably wrong with the setup or configuration (?), but cannot figure out what exactly. I have Visual Studio 2019 installed (the latest one at the moment of writing, 16.3.9). The application is set to target .NET CORE 3.0, that should support `<ComReference ...>` element.

How do I build an application that has a COM REFERENCE with .NET CORE 3.0 using Visual Studio 2019? I am building from VS2019 IDE. As of my understanding, it should not even look for the "AxImp", it should probably look for the "TlbImp". Also, why is it looking for Visual Studio 2010?? Windows SDK is installed. Does it need some specific version? Which one?

I tried to remove and then add the reference again using project references, nothing changed. Am I missing something?

Comment: @HansPassant Looks like versioning problem. It started working after I installed .NET SDK 4.7.2 (did not work with default 4.8 SDK) Maybe the version is hardcoded somewhere?

Comment: That is plausible, the 4.8 SDK was not yet done when VS2019 first shipped, so just about everybody has the 4.7.2 SDK installed.  That they then forgot to update msbuild was then an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing .NET SDK 4.7.2 the problem is gone. I had 4.8 version before (installed by default with VS 2019)